# Why django cant find a photo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, web

i wrote  in html file, django cant find a photo [this is a media files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyspx.png)

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y/%m/%d/", default=None, verbose_name="Фото")
    ingredients = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    directions = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

maybe problem in models

On site i see img icom instead full image

Comment: Img icom? Exactly *what* does it show?

Comment: https://www.analyticdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/unnamed-574x675.gif

Comment: and how did you render this in the template?

Comment: i use a ListView in views and declare model and context_object_name, without methods

Comment: but you render a template in the `ListView`?

Comment: No, i dont declare method in ListVIew, i thought ListView do it for me or not?

Comment: so there is no `template_name=...` or you dont have a `modelname_list.html` template or something similiar...

Answer (score 0):

Did you write this code in the setting.py file?

```
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Or did you write this in the main file urls.py?

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_URL)
```

Note: Write your address below
Or maybe you have a problem with the template codes